Kernels die running parallel Eigensystem[]
I am diagonalising random (real) symmetric matrices M of sizes N up to $\sim 10^3$, doing it around $5.10^4$ times. For $N\ge330$, some kernels seem to die during the evaluation of Eigensystem[M] in the ParallelDo, and never complete the evaluation. I do not understand why, and I don't think it's a memory issue (I work on MMA 13.0 with my MacBook Pro Intel 8 cores 64GB RAM OS 11.7.10). Can anyone reproduce this issue and is there any way to avoid it?
Here is a minimal code:
L=330;
Nmax=50000;

ParallelDo[
 
 bands = {Band[{1, 2}] -> RandomReal[1, L - 1], Band[{1, L}] -> RandomReal[]};
 
 Mrand = SparseArray[bands, {L, L}];
 
 M = UpperTriangularize[Mrand, 1] + Transpose[UpperTriangularize[Mrand,1]] //Normal;

 Eigensystem[M] //Transpose //Sort;

, {i, 1, Nmax}];


I tried it with MMA 13.3 on my Apple M1 Max under macos 14.4.1. It seems to run trhough in 2 half minutes without problems. But that does probably not mean anything, if your machine has an Intel CPU. IIRC, Mathematica uses the LAPACK implementation from the Intel MKL on Intel CPUs, but the one of OpenBLAS on Apple Silicon. So the code paths are likely quite different.

Indeed I have an Intel CPU. Thanks for testing it. I have tried everything, from restarting my laptop to clean install MMA, still the same issue..

Hm. Then you should definitely tell Wolfram Support about it. Make sure to include the link to this page with the minimal example.

For the time being, I recommend to write a LibraryLink function with a direct call to LAPACK. Then you can decide to link it directly against the Intel MKL, OpenBLAS, or, since you work on a Mac, with Apple's Accelerate framework. In the latter case you should make sure that a rather new Command Line Tools version is installed. Apple refurbished their LAPACK implementation last year (because it used to be somewhat buggy beforehand).

I have never done that, I'll look into it then. If you can post a minimal code or provide a link with explanations on how to do this, that would be even better, thanks.

Well, I am already working on the code. Will post it soon. ^^

Run this first to compile the code.
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
Quiet[LibraryFunctionUnload[cSymmetricEigensystemWorkSize]];
ClearAll[cSymmetricEigensystemWorkSize];
cSymmetricEigensystemWorkSize = Module[{lib,file,filename,name},
    name = "cSymmetricEigensystemWorkSize";
    Print["Compiling "<>name<>"..."];
    file=Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory,name<>".cpp"}],
        StringJoin["
        #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
        
        #define LAPACK_DISABLE_NAN_CHECK
        //#define ACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK
        
        #include <vector>
        #include <algorithm>
        #include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
        
        EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int "<>name<>"(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
        {
            int n = static_cast<int>(MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]));
        
            mreal * U    = nullptr;
            mreal * eigs = nullptr; 
        
            std::vector<mreal> work (1);
        
            int info  =  0;
        
            char job  = 'V';
            char flag = 'L';
        
            int lwork = -1;
            #ifdef LAPACK_dsyev
                LAPACK_dsyev( &job, &flag, &n, U, &n, eigs, &work[0], &lwork[, &info );
            #else
                dsyev_      ( &job, &flag, &n, U, &n, eigs, &work[0], &lwork, &info );
            #endif
        
            MArgument_setInteger(Res, static_cast<mint>(work[0]));
            
            return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
        }"],
    "Text"];
    lib=CreateLibrary[{file},name,
        "Language"->"C++"
        ,"TargetDirectory"-> $TemporaryDirectory
        ,"ShellOutputFunction"->Print
        ,"CompileOptions"->{
            "-Wall"
            ,"-Wextra"
            ,"-Wno-unused-parameter"
            (*,"-mmacosx-version-min=13.3.0"*)
            ,"-std=c++17"
            ,"-mcpu=native -mtune=native"
            ,"-fno-math-errno"
            ,"-framework Accelerate"
            ,"-ffast-math"
            ,"-Ofast"
            ,"-gline-tables-only"
            ,"-gcolumn-info"
        }
    ];
    LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,name,
        {
            Integer
        },
        Integer
    ]
];

Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
Quiet[LibraryFunctionUnload[cSymmetricEigensystem]];
ClearAll[cSymmetricEigensystem];
cSymmetricEigensystem = Module[{lib,file,filename,ds,class,name,kernel},
    name = "cSymmetricEigensystem";
    filename = name;
    Print["Compiling "<>name<>"..."];
    file=Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory,filename<>".cpp"}],
        StringJoin["
        #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
        
        #define LAPACK_DISABLE_NAN_CHECK
        //#define ACCELERATE_NEW_LAPACK
        
        #include <vector>
        #include <algorithm>
        #include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
        
        EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int "<>name<>"(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
        {
            MTensor A_    = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]); 
            MTensor U_    = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[1]); 
            MTensor eigs_ = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[2]); 
            MTensor work_ = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[3]); 
        
            int n     = static_cast<int>(libData->MTensor_getDimensions(A_)[0]);    
            int lwork = static_cast<int>(libData->MTensor_getDimensions(work_)[0]);
        
            const mreal * A    = libData->MTensor_getRealData(A_);
                  mreal * U    = libData->MTensor_getRealData(U_);  
                  mreal * eigs = libData->MTensor_getRealData(eigs_);   
                  mreal * work = libData->MTensor_getRealData(work_);   
        
        
            std::copy_n( A, n * n, U );
        
            int info  =  0;
        
            char job  = 'V';
            char flag = 'L';
        
            #ifdef LAPACK_dsyev
                LAPACK_dsyev( &job, &flag, &n, U, &n, eigs, work, &lwork, &info );
            #else
                dsyev_      ( &job, &flag, &n, U, &n, eigs, work, &lwork, &info );
            #endif
            
            libData->MTensor_disown(U_);
            libData->MTensor_disown(eigs_);
            libData->MTensor_disown(work_);

            return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
        }"],
    "Text"];
    lib=CreateLibrary[{file},filename,
        "Language"->"C++"
        ,"TargetDirectory"-> $TemporaryDirectory
        ,"ShellOutputFunction"->Print
        ,"CompileOptions"->{
            "-Wall"
            ,"-Wextra"
            ,"-Wno-unused-parameter"
            (*,"-mmacosx-version-min=13.3.0"*)
            ,"-std=c++17"
            ,"-mcpu=native -mtune=native"
            ,"-fno-math-errno"
            ,"-framework Accelerate"
            ,"-ffast-math"
            ,"-Ofast"
            ,"-gline-tables-only"
            ,"-gcolumn-info"
        }
    ];
    LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,name,
        {
            {Real,2,"Constant"},
            {Real,2,"Shared"},
            {Real,1,"Shared"},
            {Real,1,"Shared"}
        },
        "Void"
    ]
];

Then run this:
L = 330;
Nmax = 50000;
m = cSymmetricEigensystemWorkSize[L];
Quiet[LaunchKernels[]];
threadCount = Length[ParallelKernels[]];

ParallelDo[
   work = ConstantArray[0., {m}];
   M = ConstantArray[0., {L, L}];
   U = ConstantArray[0., {L, L}];
   \[Lambda] = ConstantArray[0., {L}];
   
   Do[
    M = Normal[
      SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> RandomReal[1, L - 1], 
        Band[{1, L}] -> RandomReal[]}, {L, L}]];
    cSymmetricEigensystem[M, U, \[Lambda], work];
    , {Quotient[Nmax, threadCount]}];
   
   , {threadCount}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]; // AbsoluteTiming

cSymmetricEigensystem assumes that M is symmetric and reads only the values in the upper triangle. The eigenvectors U and the eigenvalues \[Lambda] are passed by reference. So you want to keep them, you have to copy them elsewhere. (You need to make a deep copy for that, as Mathematica's MTensor objects are actually pointers.)
Each thread needs its own work space work. In order to reduce memory reallocations, I let the ParallelDo run only over the number of kernels; and I give each kernel a tight loop of jobs to work on. The drawback is that you won't get any useful progress statistics.
Overall, the code is a bit slower than Mathematica's Eigensystem on my machine. I think that Mathematica uses OpenBLAS here, and I am not surprised that their algorithms might be faster than the one in Apple's Accelerate framework.

Thanks for that! Do the eigenvectors and eigenvalues come sorted in the same order like with Eigensystem[]?

Hi Kaio, yes, the LAPACK standard for dsyev mandates that the eigenvalues come out in ascending order. I hope these routines work for you.

Hi Henrik, just tried this morning, but it does not seem to work on my machine.. When I try to evaluate cSymmetricEigensystem I get the following error: ConstantArray: "Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at \ position 2 of ConstantArray[0.,{LibraryFunctionLoad[<<1>>][6]}]." (I took L=6)

Hm. Did you get any error messages when you evaluated the lengthy code block? Also make sure that the macos Command Line Tools are installed. (That installs the C compiler.) Just run xcode-select --install in the terminal to do that.

No error messages when I evaluate the lengthy code block. I do have CLT installed, weird..

Hm. Indeed weird. I have no idea what the problem is. Maybe Mathematica did not find the compiler? Can you run the examples from this page? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/Compilation.html

No error from the examples from the documentation. I don't understand what's going on.. I'll try another clean install for everything later if I find the courage.. Thanks for your help Henrik, really appreciate it!

Ah, there was an XCode update lingering around today... Maybe that is the reason. Please go to System Settings -> Software Update and install all available updates manually.

Still doesn't work after updating.. I guess I'll have to try a full clean install.. BUT, I found that if I do Eigensystem[H, Method -> "Banded"] specifying the method, then it works without freezing anymore! I am embarrassed to not have tried that before.. Thank you very much for your help Henrik!

Uh well. I could have come up the the idea, too. It is indeed a very good idea to specify the matrix as banded. IIRC, just a aingle Householder reflection is needed to take you matrix to triadiagonal form, and that is typically the $O(n^3)$ part of the job, while the QR algorithm for tridiagonal matrices is $O(n^2)$. So this should solve your eigenvalue problems in $O(n^2)$ instead of $O(n^3)$ flops.
